# Puppeteer & Cucumber Selecting one class (from 48 with same class) and clicking on it

Tags: testing, cucumber, puppeteer

I have this problem since yesterday and can't figuered out how to solve it. The problem is that I have 48 buttons with same class (the childs are the same too). Tried using xpath, other classes inside but nothing work.

It work creating an array with all buttons and then pressing on it with "button[number]" but I don't know exactly which number is every button. The last thing that I did was create this loop to check the page by clicking on every single button (may be redirected to the correct one) but didn't work. Maybe I wrote something wrong.

```
When('I press the Users tab', async function () {
const tabToPress = await scope.page.$$('.ng-star-inserted');
var numberToPress;
for (var index = 0; index < tabToPress.length; index++) {
    await tabToPress[index].click();
    const desiredPage = `https://3.0.testing.azavista.com/users/users`;
    const currentPage = await scope.page.url();
    if (currentPage === desiredPage) {
        numberToPress = index
    }
};
await tabToPress[numberToPress].click();
await scope.page.waitFor(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting the code changed so the buttons have an id attached to them. Then you can choose which button to press without having to go through some complex shenanigans with xpath.

Your test is clearly telling you that your code needs changing. Don't ignore this feedback or try and work around it, pass it back to the people who wrote the code.